# I can't get ::after to show content in a table

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to put text in a specific table cell in parentheses by using ::before and ::after. The cell content itself is pulled from a advanced custom fields form, and in theory, would be inserted between the parentheses.

I have the following css

```
#ingredients td:nth-child(4)::before {content:"(";}
#ingredients td:nth-child(4)::after {content:")";}
```

The opening parentheses shows up as it should, but I can't get the closing one to show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code, working fine here...

```css
#ingredients td:nth-child(4)::before {
  content: "(";
}

#ingredients td:nth-child(4)::after {
  content: ")";
}
```

```html
<table id="ingredients">
  <tr>
    <td>blahblah</td>
    <td>blahblah</td>
    <td>blahblah</td>
    <td>blahblah</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```